# Getting undefined method error "bills" nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, nested

Getting undefined method 'bills' bills controller index#view

I already have my files on gist. If someone could take a look It would be helpful.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cb5a3d3077319a1892f1

Answer (score 0):

Are you defining `@user` somewhere (like in you application controller)?

If not, `BillsController#index` sets `@user` to `nil` which doesn't have a method `bills`.

**TL;DR** - Define `@user`.

Comment: The user controller is In the gist. Is that where you mean? User is defined there.

Comment: Problem is that the `BillsController` doesn't know that (the controllers cant talk to each other, but the `ApplicationController` can define a `current_user` method that you can share). Try just defining `@user` in the `BillsController#index` action first, and then you can refactor to cover more actions.